# Image element with source set to fetch from a uri, renders blank when the app is built

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, clerk

I have a screen which contains an Image element, with its source set to fetch the uri from a userobject defined by Clerk Authentication ( It extracts the profile image of the user on sign-in, and this imageUri has to be passed as a source to the Image element ) .
The issue arises that when the app renders, a blank image is displayed.

```
import { View, Image,Text,StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useUser } from '@clerk/clerk-react'

export default function Header() {

    const {user, isLoading} = useUser();
    // console.log(user);
    console.log(user?.imageUrl);

  return user&&(
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Homescreen Header</Text>
        <Image source={{uri:user?.imageUrl}}
        onError={(error) => console.error('Image loading error:', error)}
        />
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    userprofileimg: {
        width: 45,
        height: 45,
    }

})
```

[Blank Image Rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsKrE.png)

I tried console logging the imageURI extracted from the userObject, and the url is correct.

I even tried setting the source uri to be any random image from the internet, the issue seems to persist for any image with its source set to a uri / url. The app just renders blank instead of the image.

Comment: Though the image url may be correct . Mobile devices will not load that if that url is not https . Maybe thats what happened in your case .

Answer (score 0):

A network image needs width and height specified.

```js
<Image
  style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
  source={{
    uri: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300',
  }}
/>
```